# Variable declare & Assign value in C++

Tags: c++

Is it possible to declare a variable without assigning value in C++?

`int a;` `int a=15;` Which one will be Correct?

If i assign value to a variable 3 times or more which one will count at the end in C++??
`int a=15;
int a=10;
int a=5;` 
Which value will be execute for `a` at the end?

Comment: Can you show a specific example of code you are concerned about?

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve]

Comment: @RichardCritten Thank you for your advise.

Comment: @CoryKramer I am a Beginner of C++ coding

Comment: I can see that, but that does not help answer your question.

Comment: @Engr.KaziShahadatHossain Maybe you should get one of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) so that you don't have to go through asking similar questions in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cpp
int a; // declared but not assigned
a = 1; // assigning a value
a = 2; // assigning a different value
a = 3; // assigning another value
std::cout << a << "\n"; // will print 3 since only the last assignment matters
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. Now its clear to me

Comment: This make the clear sense for a beginer

Answer (score 2):

`int x;` declares a variable `x` without assigning a value.

If you assign to a variable three times then which ever assignment executed last will be the variables final value. Very important idea, C++ statements execute in a specific order, and which order they execute in is essential to understanding what a program does.

Comment: Thank you Can you Please give an Example so that i can clearly understand.

Comment: @Aplet123 gave you a good example.